# jquery toggle between two ULs when clicking a link

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to grasp my head around hiding and showing two ULs. I am trying to create a product specs table. If i could get some help completing this, its  late and i've been struggling on this for the last hour or two..

You can see a live example here: http://saeledlights.com/products/led-light-bars/high-performance-single-row/

### How the product specs table looks:

[image]

### Scenario:

When a user visits the product page the first-toggle will always be visible. When they click on second/third/fourth toggle it will change the `<ul>` and hide all others. The `<ul>` and the toggle buttons have matching class names except the buttons have a -toggle at the end.

**Here is the html:**

```
<div class="single-product row">
  <div class="grid_3 alpha">
    <img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/SW12231_thumbnail.png" alt="SW12231_thumbnail" width="200" height="200" class="alignnone product-image size-full wp-image-151" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid_9 product-specs-container omega">
    <ul class="product-specs first">
      <li><strong>MODEL:</strong>SW12231-6F</li>
      <li><strong>WATTS:</strong>24W</li>
      <li><strong>TYPE:</strong>FLOOD</li>
      <li><strong>LED's:</strong>6 x 5W Cree</li>
      <li><strong>AMP DRAW 12V/24V:</strong>1.65/0.93</li>
      <li><strong>RAW LUMENS:</strong>2250</li>
      <li><strong>IP RATING:</strong>68</li>
      <li><strong>BEAM DISTANCE:</strong>1083'</li>
      <li><strong>PEAK BEAM INTENSITY (cd):</strong>22400</li>
      <li><strong>SIZE:</strong>7.38 x 1.6 x 3.3</li>
      <li><strong>VOLTAGE:</strong>9V-30V</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="product-specs second">
      <li><strong>MODEL:</strong>1234124412231-6F</li>
      <li><strong>WATTS:</strong>12341244W</li>
      <li><strong>TYPE:</strong>12341244OOD</li>
      <li><strong>LED's:</strong>12341244x 5W Cree</li>
      <li><strong>AMP DRAW 12V/24V:</strong>1234124465/0.93</li>
      <li><strong>RAW LUMENS:</strong>1234124450</li>
      <li><strong>IP RATING:</strong>12341244</li>
      <li><strong>BEAM DISTANCE:</strong>1234124483'</li>
      <li><strong>PEAK BEAM INTENSITY (cd):</strong>12341244400</li>
      <li><strong>SIZE:</strong>1234124438 x 1.6 x 3.3</li>
      <li><strong>VOLTAGE:</strong>12341244-30V</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="grid_9 alpha omega">
      <div class="product-thumbnail"><a href="#" class="first-toggle">SPOT</a></div><div class="product-thumbnail"><a href="#" class="second-toggle">FLOOD</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### The Jquery i have so far.

```
$('.first-toggle').toggle(function(){
    var first   = $(this).closest('.single-product').children('.product-specs-container').children('.first');
    var second  = $(this).closest('.single-product').children('.product-specs-container').children('.second');
    second.removeClass('hidden current').addClass('hidden');
    first.removeClass('hidden current').addClass('current');
}, function(){
    second.removeClass('hidden current').addClass('hidden');
    first.removeClass('hidden current').addClass('current');
});
```

Comment: can u create a fiddle for this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this :  http://jsfiddle.net/czSU8/2/

```
$(" ul.second").addClass('hidden');

  $('.first-toggle').click(function(){
  var first   = $(this).closest('.single-product').children('.product-specs-container').children('.first');
  var second  = $(this).closest('.single-product').children('.product-specs-container').children('.second');
  second.removeClass('hidden current').addClass('hidden');
  first.removeClass('hidden current').addClass('current');
  event.preventDefault();
});

$('.second-toggle').click(function(){
   var first   = $(this).closest('.single-product').children('.product-specs-container').children('.first');
  var second  = $(this).closest('.single-product').children('.product-specs-container').children('.second');
  first.removeClass('hidden current').addClass('hidden');
  second.removeClass('hidden current').addClass('current');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Note: toggle() is deprecated as of jQuery 1.9 and later**

Comment: I love this solution, a bit of modification for styling purposes. I prefer to not rely on jquery to hide all the additional specs. So ill probably setup some initial styling and use jquery to remove the class but this is perfect. If i could award a bounty I would for this. Thanks A.V!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(" ul.second").addClass('hidden');
$('a.first-toggle').click(function(){
      $('ul.second').toggle();
      $('ul.first').toggle();         
};


$('a.second-toggle').click(function(){
      $('ul.second').toggle();
      $('ul.first').toggle();         
};
```

Refer http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it all wrong..

you cannot have two callbacks in toggle functions.... 
note: toggle is deprecated as of jquery 1.9 (to my knowledge)...

so from what ever i understood.. i created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zJCnz/) so that you can have a look

i used `hide()` and `slideDown()` to give it a toggle effect...

here is the code..

**html**

```
<div class="product-thumbnail"><a href="#" class="first">SPOT</a></div> // removed -toggle
<div class="product-thumbnail"><a href="#" class="second">FLOOD</a></div> // removed -toggle
```

**jquery**

```
 $('ul').not('.first').hide();  <-- hide all ul expect first here
 $('div.product-thumbnail a').click(function(){  //call click function in buttons
    var classname=$(this).attr('class'); // get the clicked button class..i removed `-toggle` here so that i can handle this with one function
   $('ul').hide(); // hide all ui first 
   $('ul.'+classname).slideDown(); //slidedown the one you clicked 
});
```

**NOTE: this will work for multiple `<ui>` just that the button should be created and button class should be exactly yhe same with the `<ui>`'s class**